# Access VBA cannot load a streetview to an image control

Tags: google-maps, ms-access, google-maps-api-3, vba

If I put a shape on an Excel Spreadsheet and run this VBA code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("myShape").Fill.UserPicture "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?&location=51.499473,-0.12902&size=256x256&heading=0&sensor=false"
```

Then a `streetview` Image shows immediately in the shape.

Now, fast forward to me trying to do the same in MS Access - I put an Image control on an Access form and run this:

```
Me.myImage.Picture = LoadPicture("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?&location=51.499473,-0.12902&size=256x256&heading=0&sensor=false")
```

I get an error:

```
Microsoft Access can't open the file [then shows URL as above]
```

I can't seem to use an unbound Object frame either, and various permutations of the URL don't help.

I know that I can use the Access Web Browser control, but I don't want to do that.

I also know how to download the image to a temp file on the C drive, and then load it into the image control. But I'd like to know if possible how to do it in 1 step (avoiding the temp file.

So, any ideas on how to load the `streetview` image directly into an Image control on an Access form?

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using the wrong control. use a WebBrowser control and it should work for you. In Access 2007 + :

[image: Control and link]

[image: Control activated with picture from google map]